# Can I use VBA to unzip a file using the native windows unzip feature?

Tags: vba, unzip, outlook-2003

I'm using Outlook 2003 & I want to use a macro to unzip a file attachment on a message.  Can I use the built-in zip file handling of windows in VBA to do this and if so, how?  I'm running on Windows7 64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer at [Windows built-in ZIP compression script-able?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/windows-built-in-zip-compression-script-able) might have some solutions.  If not I've successfully used the open source Info Zip DLLs to zip and unzip files.   See [Compression DLLs, OCXs, etc](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/compression.htm) for links and sample code.