# VB script to zip a file and give the zip file the name of the file

Tags: vbscript

Need help with VB script to zip a file in a folder and give the zip file created the name of the original name of the file. Like if there is a trn file named abc.trn then want to create a  zip file named abc.zip. Please help if anyone have any idea

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted) it is not possible using VBscript alone.

> There are VBA methods to zip and unzip using the windows built in
>   compression as well, which should give some insight as to how the
>   system operates. You may be able to build these methods into a
>   scripting language of your choice.

However, you can use an "implementation-dependent behavior of the Windows shell" (again, quoted from the same source)

```
Dim fso, winShell, MyTarget, MySource, file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set winShell = createObject("shell.application")


MyTarget = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
MySource = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

Wscript.Echo "Adding " & MySource & " to " & MyTarget

'create a new clean zip archive
Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(MyTarget, True)
file.write("PK" & chr(5) & chr(6) & string(18,chr(0)))
file.close

winShell.NameSpace(MyTarget).CopyHere winShell.NameSpace(MySource).Items

do until winShell.namespace(MyTarget).items.count = winShell.namespace(MySource).items.count
    wscript.sleep 1000 
loop

Set winShell = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```