# Batch Code to Zip up a folder?

Tags: batch-file, zip

I would like to be able to create a batch script that will zip up a directory specified in the command. Then I would like to call it info.zip. Any help would be wonderful! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Windows' built-in ZIP compression be scripted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted)

Answer (score 0):

you can use 7zip that can be called from command line with lots of parameters. You can find some good examples [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to install any thing? I really don't care if I have to use Visual Basic, or anything.

Comment: Windows doesn't have native ability to do this through the command-line.

Comment: Having a 7zip deployed on a shared file system is always useful for this type of script. I recommend to deploy it, it will save you a lot of time and can be used by lots of different scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try this edit ware appropriate.

```
Dim fso, winShell, MyTarget, MySource, file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set winShell = createObject("shell.application")


MyTarget = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
MySource = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

Wscript.Echo "Adding " & MySource & " to " & MyTarget

'create a new clean zip archive
Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(MyTarget, True)
file.write("PK" & chr(5) & chr(6) & string(18,chr(0)))
file.close

winShell.NameSpace(MyTarget).CopyHere winShell.NameSpace(MySource).Items

do until winShell.namespace(MyTarget).items.count = winShell.namespace(MySource).items.count
    wscript.sleep 1000 
loop

Set winShell = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Source: [Can Windows' built-in ZIP compression be scripted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted?lq=1)